# Magento model save method updating a record instead of inserting

Tags: php, mysql, magento, magento-1.9

I have an array of image IDs and I am iterating on it to insert them in the database table 'slider_images'. Below is code snippet:

```
        try {
            $sliderImages= Mage::getModel('gallery/sliderImage')->getCollection()
                ->addFieldToFilter('slider_id', array('eq' => $sliderId));

            $sliderImageIds = array_column($sliderImages->getData(), 'gallery_image_id');

            $addImageIds = array_diff($galleryImageIds,$sliderImageIds);
            $deleteImageIds = array_diff($sliderImageIds, $galleryImageIds);

            foreach ($addImageIds as $addImageId) {
                $sliderImageData = array();
                $sliderImageModel = Mage::getModel('gallery/sliderImage');

                $sliderImageData['slider_id'] = $sliderId;
                $sliderImageData['gallery_image_id'] = $addImageId;

                $sliderImageModel->addData($sliderImageData)->save();
            }

            foreach ($deleteImageIds as $deleteImageId) {
                $deleteSliderImageModel = Mage::getModel('gallery/sliderImage');
                $deleteSliderImageModel->setGalleryImageId($deleteImageId)->delete();
            }

            $this->_getSession()->addSuccess(
                $this->__('Total of %d record(s) were successfully updated', count($galleryImageIds))
            );
        }catch (Exception $e) {
            $this->_getSession()->addError($e->getMessage());
        }
```

Here **$addImageIds** is an array of image ids:

```
Array ( [0] => 1 [2] => 2 )
```

**Problem:**  Here it is updating a record, instead of inserting a new one. If I checked a query log

```
UPDATE `slider_images` SET `gallery_image_id` = '1' WHERE (slider_id='11')

UPDATE `slider_images` SET `gallery_image_id` = '2' WHERE (slider_id='11')
```

and table schema is like below

[image]

I want insert those values instead of update.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Call `$sliderImageModel->unsetData();` After `save` method in loop.

**Update**
change code like below:

```
unset($sliderImages);
foreach ($addImageIds as $addImageId) {
    $sliderImageData = array();
    $sliderImageModel = Mage::getModel('gallery/sliderImage');

    $sliderImageData['slider_id'] = $sliderId;
    $sliderImageData['gallery_image_id'] = $addImageId;

    $sliderImageModel->addData($sliderImageData)->save();
    $sliderImageModel->unsetData();
    unset($sliderImageModel);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for response.Did same thing as you mentioned, Still It is updating.

Comment: Yes checked almost 2-3 times. Any conflict with above getCollection() method ?

Comment: I have edited code as you said But again executing update query.Also I have added table schema to question.

Answer (score 0):

Place in your resource model `gallery/sliderImage`

```
protected $_isPkAutoIncrement = false;
```